# POST request Join channel- Error in fabric sample balance-transfer example

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

```
$./testAPIs.sh
```

POST request Enroll on Org1  ...

```
{"success":true,"secret":"","message":"Jim enrolled Successfully","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NzQ3ODQ2MjgsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiSmltIiwib3JnTmFtZSI6Ik9yZzEiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzQ3NDg2Mjh9.z-R6C5jAffwW-pDKZ80Cp4F9TNdfVKnd71e52KKlZz0"}
```

ORG1 token is

`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NzQ3ODQ2MjgsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiSmltIiwib3JnTmFtZSI6Ik9yZzEiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzQ3NDg2Mjh9.z-R6C5jAffwW-pDKZ80Cp4F9TNdfVKnd71e52KKlZz0`

POST request Enroll on Org2 ...

```
{"success":true,"secret":"","message":"Barry enrolled Successfully","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NzQ3ODQ2MjksInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiQmFycnkiLCJvcmdOYW1lIjoiT3JnMiIsImlhdCI6MTU3NDc0ODYyOX0.yDOu_14YW3C33HyrLqkxEBQiJh57eoxW7X2pLUuD5IU"}
```

ORG2 token is

`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NzQ3ODQ2MjksInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiQmFycnkiLCJvcmdOYW1lIjoiT3JnMiIsImlhdCI6MTU3NDc0ODYyOX0.yDOu_14YW3C33HyrLqkxEBQiJh57eoxW7X2pLUuD5IU`

POST request Create channel  ...

POST request Join channel on Org1

```
{"success":false,"message":"Failed to join all peers to channel. cause:Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7050"}
```

POST request Join channel on Org2

```
{"success":false,"message":"Failed to join all peers to channel. cause:Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7050"}
```

Comment: Maybe post the script content?

Comment: dude it seems to be issue with the ':ports' can share docker-compose.yaml or docker-compose-base.yaml files.